# oprofile 0.9.8 failing under Ubuntu 12.10 with Pentium D

Tags: linux, ubuntu, profiling, oprofile

I am trying to use oprofile 0.9.8 under Ubuntu 12.10 running on a Pentium D processor (Dell OptiPlex-GX620 desktop). When I try something simple like "operf ls" I get

```
perf_event_open failed with Invalid argument
Caught runtime_error: Internal Error.  Perf event setup failed.
Error running profiler
```

I have success running oprofile in legacy mode using opcontrol commands under sudo by installing the module with timer=1 (see below).

It appears that operf is unhappy in this configuration - which is the new preferred method.

I have verified that all the dependent packages are loaded.

On the oprofile website they do not call out pentium D as a seperate architucture so not sure if it is using regular Pentium architecture.

I have searched everywhere and can't find anything like this reported. Any help would be appreciated in identifying the problem here.

P.S. When I run with legacy mode using opcontrol I have some success:

```
denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ sudo opcontrol --start
ATTENTION: Use of opcontrol is discouraged.  Please see the man page for operf.
Using default event: GLOBAL_POWER_EVENTS:100000:1:1:1
Error: counter 0 not available nmi_watchdog using this resource ? Try:
opcontrol --deinit
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog

**When I force the module to be installed with timer=1**

denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ sudo opcontrol --deinit
Unloading oprofile module
denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ sudo modprobe oprofile timer=1
denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ sudo opcontrol --no-vmlinux
denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ sudo opcontrol --start
ATTENTION: Use of opcontrol is discouraged.  Please see the man page for operf.
Using 2.6+ OProfile kernel interface.
Using log file /var/lib/oprofile/samples/oprofiled.log
Daemon started.
Profiler running.
denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ ./a
^C
denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ sudo opcontrol --shutdown

Stopping profiling.
Killing daemon.
denham@denham-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ opreport --callgraph
Using /var/lib/oprofile/samples/ for samples directory.
warning: /no-vmlinux could not be found.
warning: [vdso] (tgid:1697 range:0xb77ab000-0xb77ac000) could not be found.
warning: [vdso] (tgid:1728 range:0xb77b6000-0xb77b7000) could not be found.
warning: [vdso] (tgid:3310 range:0xb7702000-0xb7703000) could not be found.
CPU: CPU with timer interrupt, speed 2992.41 MHz (estimated)
Profiling through timer interrupt
samples  %        image name               app name                 symbol name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31878    81.1868  no-vmlinux               no-vmlinux               /no-vmlinux
  31878    100.000  no-vmlinux               no-vmlinux               /no-vmlinux [self]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2820      7.1820  a                        a                        main
  2820     100.000  a                        a                        main [self]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1065      2.7123  vino-server              vino-server              /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
  1065     100.000  vino-server              vino-server              /usr/lib/vino/vino-server [self]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1056      2.6894  a                        a                        b
  1056     100.000  a                        a                        b [self]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1013      2.5799  a                        a                        c
  1013     100.000  a                        a                        c [self]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
968       2.4653  a                        a                        d
  968      100.000  a                        a                        d [self]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
264       0.6724  libc-2.15.so             libc-2.15.so             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
 . . . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the main problem but the error message says -

> "Error: counter 0 not available nmi_watchdog using this resource.
>   Try: opcontrol --deinit echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog".

To get rid of this you have to disable NMI watchdog kernel parameter. On Ubuntu it is done via `grub` -

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `“nmi_watchdog=0”` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`.
2. Then run `sudo update-grub` and check the value with 
   `cat /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog` (should be "0"). Reboot to install new config if needed.